# Why is this html5 canvas animation so intensive?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I create this animaiton using canvas and converting svg's to canvas shapes. Most times it runs it heats up my computer and the fan starts going.

Just wondering if there is something about the code, html5 canvas, canvas paths or the animation recursion that is so intensive?

View on codepen: https://codepen.io/benbyford-the-lessful/pen/ZjjVdR?editors=1010#

```
    // check program is being run

console.log('bg animation running...');


// setup canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('bgCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// redo this - canvas size
//
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = width * 2;
canvas.height = height * 2;

var gridSquareWidth = 20;
var gridWidth = (width * 2) / gridSquareWidth,
    gridHeight = (height * 2) / gridSquareWidth;



var grid = [];

// create default grid array
for (var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
    grid[x] = [];

    for (var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
        var rand  = getRandomArbitrary(0,5);
        var rand2  = getRandomArbitrary(0,2);

        if(rand2 == 1 || x < (gridWidth / 4) || x > (gridWidth / 2) || y < (gridHeight / 4) || y > (gridHeight / 2)){
            rand--;
        }

        if(rand > 2) grid[x][y] = 1;
    }
}


//
// main update function
//
var animationSpeed = 0.1;
var animationSpeedCount = 0;
var running = true;
function update(dt) {

    if(running){
        animationSpeedCount += dt;
        if(animationSpeedCount > animationSpeed){

            moveGrid();
            animationSpeedCount = 0;
        }

        draw();
    }
}

var noOfFrames = 3;
var waveOffset = 15;
var increment = 0;
function moveGrid() {

    var x = increment;
    var x2 = increment - noOfFrames - waveOffset;

    // add frmae wave
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfFrames; i++) {
        moveONeFrameForward(x, true);
        x--;
    }
    // go back frmae wave
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfFrames; i++) {
        moveONeFrameForward(x2, false);
        x2--;
    }

    // var x column, add of subtract by 1
    function moveONeFrameForward(x, add){

        if(x < 0){
            x = Math.ceil(gridWidth + x);
        }

        if(x > 0 && x < gridWidth){

            for (var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
                if(grid[x][y] > 0){
                    if(add){
                        grid[x][y] = grid[x][y] + 1;
                    }else{
                        if(grid[x][y] > 1) grid[x][y] = grid[x][y] - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // increment column
    increment += 1;
    if(increment > gridWidth){
        increment = 0;

        // stop running
        // running = false;
    }
}

var fills = ["#eeeeee","#efefef","#fefefe","#ffffff"];

function draw() {
    // clear canvas to white
    ctx.fillStyle = '#dddddd';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {

            var offsetX = x * gridSquareWidth;
            var offsetY = y * gridSquareWidth;
            var frame = 0;

            switch (grid[x][y]) {
                case 1:
                    frame = 1
                    break;
                case 2:
                    frame = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    frame = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    frame = 4;
                    break;
                default:
            }
            if(frame) drawframe(ctx, frame, offsetX, offsetY, fills);
        }
    }
}


// The main game loop
var lastTime = 0;
function gameLoop() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.0;

    update(dt);

    lastTime = now;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
};

// start game
gameLoop();


//
// UTILITIES
//

// cross browser requestAnimationFrame - https://gist.github.com/mrdoob/838785
if ( !window.requestAnimationFrame ) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame = ( function() {

        return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(
            /* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement Element */ element ) {
            window.setTimeout( callback, 1000 / 60 );
        };

    })();
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}


var frame1Center = 4.1;
var frame2Center = 2.1;
function drawframe(ctx, frame, x, y, fills) {

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.fillStyle = fills[frame-1];

    switch (frame) {
        case 1:
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(3.1+x+frame1Center,0+y);
            ctx.lineTo(0.6+x+frame1Center,0+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.3+x+frame1Center,0+y,0+x+frame1Center,0.3+y,0+x+frame1Center,0.6+y);
            ctx.lineTo(0.3+x+frame1Center,12.1+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.3+x+frame1Center,12.4+y,0.6+x+frame1Center,12.7+y,0.8999999999999999+x+frame1Center,12.7+y);
            ctx.lineTo(3.4+x+frame1Center,12.7+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.6999999999999997+x+frame1Center,12.7+y,4+x+frame1Center,12.399999999999999+y,4+x+frame1Center,12.1+y);
            ctx.lineTo(4+x+frame1Center,0.6+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.1+x+frame1Center,0.3+y,3.7+x+frame1Center,0+y,3.1+x+frame1Center,0+y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            break;
        case 2 || 6:
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(4.4+x+frame2Center,0+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.1+x+frame2Center,0+y,0+x+frame2Center,0.8+y,0+x+frame2Center,2.1+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(0+x+frame2Center,3.4000000000000004+y,0.3+x+frame2Center,12.5+y,1.6+x+frame2Center,12.799999999999999+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.8+x+frame2Center,13+y,6+x+frame2Center,12+y,6+x+frame2Center,10.7+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(6+x+frame2Center,9.1+y,5.7+x+frame2Center,0+y,4.4+x+frame2Center,0+y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            break;
        case 3 || 5:
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(5.2+x,0 +y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.5 +x,0+y,9.3+x,6.5+y,9.3 +x,8.7+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.3+x,10.899999999999999+y,6.300000000000001+x,12.799999999999999+y,4.1000000000000005+x,12.799999999999999+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.9000000000000004+x,12.799999999999999+y,0+x,6.3+y,0+x,4.1+y);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(0+x,1.8999999999999995+y,3+x,0+y,5.2+x,0+y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            break;
        case 4:
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(5.9+x,6.3+y,5.8,0,6.283185307179586,true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            break;
        default:
    }
};
```

Comment: Not your issue but your last switch block seems incorrect at reading. Did you mean `case 2: case 6: ctx.beginPath...`?

Comment: And for your issue, after testing, I would say it's because you are creating a lot of sub-paths at every draw. You could try to combine them in larger sub-paths and call fill() and stroke() only for each different fillStyles, but a better improvement for this animation might be to use *drawImage*: you would generate the four possible states in 4 different canvases at init, and then only draw strips of the required ones.

Comment: @kaiido no idea how to do that but sounds cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly "why", but there are definitely some things that could be improved.

- First, you are drawing twice as big as what is needed.
  Set you canvas size to the rendered one, and you'll probably see a big improvement in performances.
- Then, you are drawing a lot of sub-path at every draw <sub>(and setting a lot of times the context's properties for nothing)</sub>.
  You could try to merge all these sub-paths in bigger ones, grouped by fillStyle, so that the rasterizer works only four times per frame. This can also improve performances a bit.

But the approach I would personally take, is to pre-render all the 4 different states on 4 different canvases. Then, use only *drawImage* to draw the required strip.
In best case, you end up with only 4 calls to drawImage, in worth one, with 8 calls.

Here is a **rough** proof of concept:

```js
// setup canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('bgCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// don't set it twice as big as needed
var width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var gridSquareWidth = 10;
var gridWidth = (width) / gridSquareWidth,
  gridHeight = (height) / gridSquareWidth;

var grid = [];

// create default grid array
for (var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
  grid[x] = [];

  for (var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
    var rand = getRandomArbitrary(0, 5);
    var rand2 = getRandomArbitrary(0, 2);

    if (rand2 == 1 || x < (gridWidth / 4) || x > (gridWidth / 2) || y < (gridHeight / 4) || y > (gridHeight / 2)) {
      rand--;
    }

    if (rand > 2) grid[x][y] = 1;
  }
}

var fills = ["#eeeeee", "#efefef", "#fefefe", "#ffffff"];

var frame1Center = 4.1;
var frame2Center = 2.1;

// the 4 points drawers
var drawers = [draw0, draw1, draw2, draw3];
// initialise our four possible states
var states = [
  initState(0),
  initState(1),
  initState(2),
  initState(3)
];

//
// main update function
//
var running = true;
var speed = 2;

var waveWidth = 200;
var waveMargin = gridSquareWidth * 4;
var waveStart = 0;
var waveEnd = waveWidth;

// start game
update();

function initState(status) {
  var c = canvas.cloneNode();
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5); // to circumvent values being set for scale(2)

  ctx.beginPath(); // single path
  ctx.fillStyle = fills[status];
  for (var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
      if (grid[x][y]) {
        drawers[status](ctx, x * gridSquareWidth * 2, y * gridSquareWidth * 2);
      }
    }
  }
  ctx.fill(); // single fill

  return c;
}

function draw0(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.moveTo(3.1 + x + frame1Center, 0 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(0.6 + x + frame1Center, 0 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.3 + x + frame1Center, 0 + y, 0 + x + frame1Center, 0.3 + y, 0 + x + frame1Center, 0.6 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(0.3 + x + frame1Center, 12.1 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.3 + x + frame1Center, 12.4 + y, 0.6 + x + frame1Center, 12.7 + y, 0.8999999999999999 + x + frame1Center, 12.7 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(3.4 + x + frame1Center, 12.7 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.6999999999999997 + x + frame1Center, 12.7 + y, 4 + x + frame1Center, 12.399999999999999 + y, 4 + x + frame1Center, 12.1 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(4 + x + frame1Center, 0.6 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.1 + x + frame1Center, 0.3 + y, 3.7 + x + frame1Center, 0 + y, 3.1 + x + frame1Center, 0 + y);
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw1(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.moveTo(4.4 + x + frame2Center, 0 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.1 + x + frame2Center, 0 + y, 0 + x + frame2Center, 0.8 + y, 0 + x + frame2Center, 2.1 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0 + x + frame2Center, 3.4000000000000004 + y, 0.3 + x + frame2Center, 12.5 + y, 1.6 + x + frame2Center, 12.799999999999999 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.8 + x + frame2Center, 13 + y, 6 + x + frame2Center, 12 + y, 6 + x + frame2Center, 10.7 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(6 + x + frame2Center, 9.1 + y, 5.7 + x + frame2Center, 0 + y, 4.4 + x + frame2Center, 0 + y);
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw2(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.moveTo(5.2 + x, 0 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.5 + x, 0 + y, 9.3 + x, 6.5 + y, 9.3 + x, 8.7 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.3 + x, 10.899999999999999 + y, 6.300000000000001 + x, 12.799999999999999 + y, 4.1000000000000005 + x, 12.799999999999999 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.9000000000000004 + x, 12.799999999999999 + y, 0 + x, 6.3 + y, 0 + x, 4.1 + y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0 + x, 1.8999999999999995 + y, 3 + x, 0 + y, 5.2 + x, 0 + y);
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw3(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.moveTo(5.9 + x, 6.3 + y);
  ctx.arc(5.9 + x, 6.3 + y, 5.8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}


function update(dt) {

  if (running) {
    draw();
    moveGrid();
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


function moveGrid() {
  waveStart = (waveStart + speed) % canvas.width;
  waveEnd = (waveStart + waveWidth) % canvas.width;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#dddddd';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var x = 0;
  // the roll logic is a bit dirty... sorry.
  if (waveEnd < waveStart) {
    x = waveEnd - waveWidth;
    drawStrip(1, x, waveMargin);

    x = waveEnd - waveWidth + waveMargin;
    drawStrip(3, x, (waveWidth - (waveMargin * 2)));

    x = waveEnd - waveMargin;
    drawStrip(2, x, waveMargin);
    x = waveEnd;
  }

  drawStrip(0, x, waveStart - x);
  drawStrip(1, waveStart, waveMargin);
  drawStrip(3, waveStart + waveMargin, waveWidth - (waveMargin * 2));
  drawStrip(2, waveStart + (waveWidth - waveMargin), waveMargin);
  drawStrip(0, waveEnd, canvas.width - Math.max(waveEnd, waveStart));
}

function drawStrip(state, x, w) {
  if(x < 0) w = w + x;
  if (w <= 0) return;
  x = Math.max(x, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(states[state],
    Math.max(x, 0), 0, w, canvas.height,
    Math.max(x, 0), 0, w, canvas.height
  );

}



function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```css
:root,body,canvas {margin: 0}
```

```html
<canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Amazing thank you, ill have to look into those suggestions